# Spring data elastic search long to localdatetime conversion error

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following mapping

```
@Document(indexName = "some-index")
@Data
public class ElasticDocument {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private LocalDateTime issuedTimestamp;

}
```

The following repository

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ElasticDocument, String> {

}
```

But the following query from spring data elastic search 4.0.3.RELEASE throws a conversion error:

```
Page<ElasticDocument> elasticDocuments = documentRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 10));
```

> [MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:290] [Type LocalDateTime of
> property ElasticDocument.issuedTimestamp is a TemporalAccessor
> class but has neither a @Field annotation defining the date type nor a
> registered converter for reading! It cannot be mapped from a complex
> object in Elasticsearch!
> [No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long]
> to type [java.time.LocalDateTime]]
> [org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
> converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to
> type [java.time.LocalDateTime]

I'm using elasticsearch 7.9.1 and spring data elasticsearch 4.0.3.RELEASE and from what i understood starting with spring data elasticsearch 4.x we don't need to create a custom conversion as long as i added the Field annotation at mapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the pattern for your custom format in the `@Field` annotation

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

Comment: can you please help me with an answer also for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953648/spring-data-elasticsearch-multiple-filters ?

Answer (score 1):

Since spring-data-elastic version 4.2, dateformat.custom is deprecated. You can use any of the enum date_hour_minute_second_xxx in `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.DateFormat`. E.g

```java
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second_millis)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```